# Proof verification of incompleteness of metric $\sigma(x,y) = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Define metric $\sigma(x,y) = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that this metric is incomplete.

I would appreciate proof verification on what I currently have.

Proof:

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Construct the sequence $x_n = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, we can find some $x$ such that $|\arctan(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Take $N$ to be the least integer greater than $x$.

We need to show that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy but not convergent. Then for any $x_n$ and $x_m$ with $n,m > N$, we have $$\sigma(x_n, x_m) = |\arctan(n) - \arctan(m)| \leq \\ |\arctan(n) - \frac{\pi}{2}| + |\arctan(m) - \frac{\pi}{2}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$. Hence, $x_n$ is cauchy. But there is no point $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x_n \to r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideas all seem to be present, although an important step is out of order.

You should start by defining the sequence $x_n = n$, before you ever "fix $\epsilon > 0$".

Next you should state your intention to prove $x_n$ is Cauchy.

Only then, by applying the definition of a Cauchy sequence, are you justified to "fix $\epsilon > 0$", and to proceed with the proof that $x_n$ is Cauchy.

Otherwise, your proof is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to justify your last sentence, that there is no $r\in \Bbb R$ (not $\Bbb R^+$)  such that $\sigma (x_n,r)\to 0.$ There are many ways to do this. For example, if $|\arctan (n)-\arctan (r)|\to 0$ then $\arctan (r)=\pi/2,$ implying $r=\tan \pi/2 ,$ which is impossible.